# How to check user is authenticated properly in Django and Backbone.js

Tags: django, authentication, backbone.js

I want to build single page application using Backbone.js and Django.

For checking user is authenticated or not,

I wrote a method get_identity method in django side.
If request.user.is_authenticated is true it returns request.user.id otherwise it returns Http404

In backbone side, I defined a User model and periodically make ajax call to get_identity.

I think it is the most straightforward way to check user is authenticated or not.

For learning single page application, I want to do this operation more sensible and efficient  than this way if it is possible.

So what is your advice about this? When I search Django+Backbone.js + User Authentication, I couldn't find any satisfactory result and I really wonder how people do this simple operation.

Any help or idea will be appreciated.

(By the way I tried to read cookie periodically but HttpOnly True flagged cookies are not reacheable in client side.)

Django views.py

```
def get_identity(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        raise Http404
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'identity':request.user.id}), mimetype="application/json")
```

Backbone.js side.

```
updateUser:function(){
            var $self=this;
            $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
            $.get(
                '/get_identity',
                function(response){
                    // update model...
                    $self.user.id =response.identity;
                    //check user every five minutes...
                     $self.user.fetch({success: function() {
                       $self.user.set('is_authenticated',true);
                       setTimeout($self.updateUser, 1000*60*1);
                        }
                    },this);
                }).fail(function(){
                    //clear model
                    $self.user.clear().set($self.user.defaults);
                    setTimeout($self.updateUser, 1000*60*1);
                });
            $.ajaxSetup({async:true});
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

I had `var is_authenticated = {{request.user.is_authenticated}};` in my base.html

and used the global variable to check.

I'm in pursuit of better solution (because this breaks when you start caching).
But you might find it useful.

Comment: ```{{ request.user.is_authenticated }}``` returns uppercase True or False which js can't understand. I had to do ```var is_loggedin = '{{ request.user.is_authenticated }}' == 'True'? true : '';```

Comment: try `{{ request.user.is_authenticated|yesno:"true,false" }};`

Comment: That's neat. Thank you.

Comment: still returns string, better to make something like this; `var isAuthenticated = '{{request.user.is_authenticated}}' === 'True';` will return js boolean.